# How to create imaged scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to create **imaged** scrollbars, for example:

http://www.openstudio.fr/jquery/index.htm

Basically, I want to create my own image slider with JQuery but I don't want to show default scrollbars. Instead, I would like to have imaged scrollbars.

How do they create custom scrollbars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for example [jScrollPane](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jScrollPane) plugin for jQuery.

Comment: Creating basic functionality isn't that difficult. This kind of scripts wrap the element into some container, set overflow hidden and position relative on the wrapper, position the content absolutely, add some additional markup for scroll-bar parts, handle mouse events on them and change positioning of the content. More complex scripts support mouse wheel and keyboard events to do the scrolling, etc.